# Jquery Datepicker with TextBox in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have the problem for jquery datepicker with textbox in asp.net but i don't have the resolve it.
Please help me! . Sorry, my grammar is not good. :D

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/jquery.datepick.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {

            $("#" + '<%=txtReleaseDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

[image]

My textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtReleaseDate" runat="server" CssClass="js-date-picker">  </asp:TextBox>
```

My textbox doesn't show datepicker

Comment: and what is this problem?

Comment: Try the following line $('input[id$=txtReleaseDate]').datepicker(); This will take all input elements where the id ends with txtReleaseDate.

Comment: You can also use only 1 set of quotes: $('#<%=txtReleaseDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();

Comment: my problem is textbox don't show datepicker

Comment: it doesn't work. please help me

Comment: You still writing wrong code.. remove  $(function () { and });

Comment: I have removed it. This is code when i removed:
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<%=txtReleaseDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();

Answer (score 2):

write your code in pageload() of javascript.

```
function pageLoad(){
   $('input[id*=txtReleaseDate]').datepicker();
}
```

Comment: I had to do this.  My date picker was inside an UpdatePanel and it gets clobbered every time the UpdatePanel gets updated (so have to re-apply the jquery datepicker() after every update, which you can do in pageLoad.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding ClientIDMode="Static" to your textbox, and then updating your script to reference $('#txtReleaseDate')... It's possible using the "<%" code is messing up your script.

If it doesn't work, what do your browser debugger tools show (F12 in IE\Chrome, Firebug in Firefox) ?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I tried add ClientIDMode="Static", it still doesn't work

Comment: @yongie and you updated your script to not use .ClientID?  What aobut the browser debugging tools?  do they show an error?

Comment: @yongie check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336(v=vs.85).aspx, if youre going to dabble in scripting, it's good to know how to debug such things..

Answer (score 0):

You defined a function without calling it.
Just remove `$(function () {`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#" + '<%=txtReleaseDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
});
```

Or execute it(not recommended):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
                $("#" + '<%=txtReleaseDate.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        })();
});
```

Comment: i have edited but textbox don't show datepicker! do you have other resolve?

Comment: Im not sure about the script that you had used, usually i use jQuery.ui.js.. just using this focus the textbox will popup the datepicker.. one more thing u should use a good browser like chrome firefox or IE9 .. (not sure about IE)

Comment: I used jquery date picker in here http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html
and i use chrome browser. But it does not work. :(

Comment: You need to include jquery and other js files too :
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datepick.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>

Comment: Thanks for help me, i don't know why it still wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
// First notation
$(function() {
    // Code here
});

// Second notation
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

These 2 code blocks are equivalent, my first advice is just pick one, the one you're more comfortable with, and stick with it.

Second advice, regarding the jQuery UI's datepicker: instead of relying on controls ids, which forces you to introduce server tags in you JS code, just choose a CSS class you'll use to tag the controls you want to apply jQuery UI datepicker to.

This way, you will keep your JS code DRY, and you can include the initialization code in the master page and not modify it.

Imagine you would choose the `js-date-picker` class as you tagging class, here's the JS you'll have to write. Note I prefer the short notation, but once again, it's up to you:

```
$(function() {
    $(".js-date-picker").datepicker({
        // Options go here   
    });
});
```

You can find the list of options [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I've always found good to go have a look at the options, so you're aware of the defaults, and you don't get surprised with some behavior that you might not have wanted.

EDIT: OK, after a second look, it's normal you don't see anything. I guess you also have a JS error when you run it. The screenshot shows you have jquery.datepick.js, which is different than jQuery UI's datepicker. I think I found the homepage of this plugin [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html).

As you can see, it shows the plugin can be invoked by calling `.datepick()` and not `.datepicker()`.
Maybe you could try that.

Comment: Thank for your comment but i don't find the result

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Paste your link file here */

    <link href="../assets/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../assets/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>   

 /* This only work with asp.net tag */
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=textbox.ClientID %>").datepicker();//paste textbox id here
        });
        </script>

    /* This work with html tag */
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#textbox").datepicker();//paste textbox id here
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is your text box. In html input if you type - type="text" will work but in asp.net text box it does not. Rather capture the change event of your text box in jquery and change the format to "dd/mm/yy".

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker();
        $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").on("change", function () {
            $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
        });
    });
</script>
```